# Bash: why echo $x prints newline if x is @?

Tags: bash

Consider this scenario:

```
$ x=y
$ echo $x
y
$ x=@
$ echo $x
<newline>
```

Why echo `$x` prints newline if `x` is `@`?

Comment: Can you verify the variable's contents using `declare -p x` or `typeset -p x`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the case!

Comment: `x="@"` maybe ?  `$ echo $BASH_VERSION $BASHOPTS` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hypothesis: your `$IFS` contains `@`.

`x=@` works as expected, there is no expansion here, `$IFS` does not matter. You can confirm that `$x` expands to `@` by passing the [properly quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) value to `echo`:

```
echo "$x"
```

Because you did not double-quote in your original code (`echo $x`), the shell used characters in `$IFS` to split the expanded value. The value `@` got split to two empty strings. Then unquoted empty strings vanished. The result was as if you run:

```
echo
```

i.e. `echo` with zero arguments. By default `echo` prints one terminating newline character.

To see all characters of your `$IFS` in a human-readable form:

```
printf '%s' "$IFS" | od -c
```

Comment: The hypothesis is correct. Forgot to set IFS to the default.